# Trying to align image and canvas

Tags: image, canvas, alignment

First-time posting a question, and I avow up front that my HTML/CSS/Javascript knowledge is ... shall we say scrappy.  I usually manage, but I can't seem to figure this out.

All I want to do is display an image centered.  Then create a canvas, position the canvas over the image, and draw on it.  ***Then*** have the canvas stay with the image as the browser is re-sized.  Here's what I have so far (I confess, I got much of the Javascript code from another poster, and I'm trying to use it as a learning example):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script>
    function myInit()
    {
    hdc = set_canvas();
    hdc.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
    }

    function set_canvas()
    {
      var img = document.getElementById('audubon_image');
      var x = img.offsetLeft,
          y = img.offsetTop,
          w = img.clientWidth,
          h = img.clientHeight;
      var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      img.parentNode.appendChild(c);
      c.style.zIndex = 1;
      c.style.left = x + 'px';
      c.style.top = y + 'px';
      c.setAttribute('width', w+'px');
      c.setAttribute('height', h+'px');
      hdc = c.getContext('2d');
      return(hdc);
    }
</script>

<style>
#container
{
    text-align: center;
}
canvas
{
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>

<body onload='myInit()'>
    <div id="container">
    <img src="http://www.sturtz.org/john/audubon/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Audubon.jpg" id="audubon_image" />
    <canvas id='myCanvas'></canvas>     <!-- gets re-positioned in myInit(); -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What's supposed to happen:  The image gets placed.  Then the Javascript code determines the position and size of the image, and sets the canvas to match.  Then draws on the canvas (for the moment, a lovely elegant block box in the upper left corner).

So far, so good.  But since the image centered, if the browser is re-sized (specifically made wider or narrower), the image's position moves relative to the left and right edges of the browser window.

With 'position: absolute' specified for the canvas, the canvas does not move (unsurprisingly; I suppose that's what absolute means).  So the image and canvas do not stay aligned.

If I change the canvas CSS to 'position: relative', then when I re-size the window, the image and canvas remain in the same position relative to one another (which is what I want).  But then I can't get the canvas over the top of the image.

My gut feel is that this should be possible (easy, even), and my lack of knowledge is causing me not to see it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm on to it.

Put the **canvas** in a **div**.  Wrap that and the **img** in a container **div**.  Specify *'position: relative'* for the outer **div**, *'position: absolute'* for the inner **div**.  That way, the x and y coordinates of the **div** containing the **canvas** may simply be specified as (0,0).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script>
    function myInit()
    {
    hdc = set_canvas();
    hdc.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
    }

    function set_canvas()
    {
    var c = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    c.style.zIndex = 1;
    c.setAttribute('width', '650px');
    c.setAttribute('height', '300px');
    hdc = c.getContext('2d');
    return(hdc);
    }
</script>
<style>
    #image_container
    {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 650px;
    position: relative;
    }
    #canvas_container
    {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    }
    #map_canvas
    {
    }
</style>
</head>

<body onload='myInit()'>
    <div id="image_container">
    <img src="http://www.sturtz.org/john/audubon/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Audubon.jpg" id="audubon_image" />
    <div id="canvas_container">
        <canvas id="map_canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

How to position the canvas directly over the img with the container horizontally centered.

**Keep the canvas directly over the image**

Set both #audubon_image and #myCanvas to `position:absolute` inside the #container that's set to `position:relative`.

**Center the container div**

`margin:0 auto;` to center #container on the page.

**CSS**

```
#container{
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
#audubon_image,#myCanvas{position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;}
#audubon_image{border:1px solid green;}
#myCanvas{ border:1px solid red;}
```

**Javascript**

Set the #container's CSS size and #canvas's element size to equal the img's size. Be sure to set the canvas **element** size (not css size) or your canvas drawings will be distorted.

```
// get a reference to #audubon_image
var img=document.getElementById('audubon_image');

// set #container's size to equal the #audubon_image size
var container=document.getElementById('container');
container.style.width=img.width+'px';
container.style.height=img.height+'px';

// set #myCanvas's size to equal the #audubon_image size
var canvas=document.getElementById('myCanvas');
canvas.width=img.width;
canvas.height=img.height;
```

Note: Once in a great while, browsers will fire `window.onload` before the image's width & height are set (shame on you browsers!). So in production, you might "defensively" wrap the javascript inside a `setTimeout` of 1 second to be sure the image's width & height have been set.

**Full code and a Demo:**

```js
window.onload = (function() {

  // get a reference to #audubon_image
  var img = document.getElementById('audubon_image');

  // set #container's size to equal the #audubon_image size
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  container.style.width = img.width + 'px';
  container.style.height = img.height + 'px';

  // set #myCanvas's size to equal the #audubon_image size
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;

});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: ivory;
}
#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
#audubon_image,
#myCanvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
#audubon_image {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
#myCanvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img id="audubon_image" src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/character3.png' />
  <canvas id='myCanvas'></canvas>
</div>
```